# smallest value of $p$

Tags: polynomials

$(x^3+px^{2}+2x-5)^{19}(x^{2}+qx-41)^{8}(x^4-x^3+x-7)^6=x^{97}+391x^{96}+a_{95}x^95+\cdots+a_1x+a_0 $be an identity ,where $p,q,a_{95},\cdots,a_{0} \ $ are integers.then the smallest possible value of $p$ is----

First of all I tried to expand the first term. I got it of the form $(x^{57}+px^{56}+ \cdots )$
Then the second term $(x^{16}+qx^{15}+ \cdots )$
Similarly the third term $(x^{24}-x^{23}+ \cdots )$
On multiplying the above three terms I got something of the form $(x^{97}+(q+p-1)x^{96}+ \cdots )$
On comparing with what given in the question I ended with $q+p-1=391$ or $p=392-q$for the minimum value of $p,q \ $ should be maximum,but I could not figure that out.thanks.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

You have not expanded any of these correctly.

$$(x^3+px^2+2x-5)^19=x^{57}+19px^{56}+(171p^2+38)x^{55}+\cdots$$

$$(x^2+qx-41)^8=x^{16}+8qx^{15}+(28q^2-328)x^{14}+\cdots$$

$$(x^4-x^3+x-7)^6=x^{24}-6x^{23}+15x^{22}+\cdots$$

Checks at WolframAlpha: [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CoefficientList%5BExpand%5B(x%5E3%20%2B%20p*x%5E2%20%2B%202%20x%20-%205)%5E19%5D,x%5D) [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CoefficientList%5BExpand%5B(x%5E2%20%2B%20q*x%20-%2041)%5E8%5D,%20x%5D) [3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CoefficientList%5BExpand%5B(x%5E4%20-%20x%5E3%20%2B%20x%20-%207)%5E6%5D,%20x%5D)

The product of these then should give:

$$x^{97}+(19p+8q-6)x^{96}+\cdots$$

So $19p+8q-6=391$

$19p+8q=397$

I'm assuming the question meant to restrict the answer to **positive** integers or you can't find the smallest.

Next:

$19=2\times8+3$

$8=2\times3+2$

$3=1\times2+1$

Hence:

$1=1\times3-1\times2$

$1=1\times3-1\times(1\times8-2\times3)=-1\times8+3\times3$

$1=-1\times8+3\times(19-2\times8)=3\times19-7\times8$

Hence:

$397=397\times(3\times19-7\times8)$

$395=1191\times19-2779\times8$

$397=1191\times19-148\times8\times19-(2765\times8-148\times19\times8)$

Note: $148$ comes from $1191\div8=148.875$

$397=(1191-1184)\times9-(2779-2812)\times8$

$397=7\times19+33\times8$

Hence the smallest $p=7$

Comment: how did you expanded the expressions

Comment: Multinomial expansion. How did you expand the expressions?